# What does it mean when a bounty time limit changes?

Tags: discussion, bounties

I'm mildly curious as to what would happen that'd make a bounty "expiration" time change. When I answered a bounty question with the right answer (and it was accepted), the bounty had about 17 hours to expire. Now (about a day later) the bounty is described as expiring 6 more days from now.  Does that mean that the question-asking user somehow extended the time horizon?

[Here's the question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888711/html5-canvas-same-code-outputs-different-results-in-different-browsers)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to have been misled by the comments. There is no change in bounty time limit, all that happened is that the author is noting when the bounty can be awarded. [BalusC](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67367/what-does-it-mean-when-a-bounty-time-limit-changes/67375#67375) quotes the relevant comment, which I'll repeat for convenience.

> yeah, you're right, going to look after that. thanks for your efforts anyway, much appreciated. Tested it a bit and, you confirmed my suspicion. Bounty will apply in 17 hours from now ;)

However, it is impossible for there to have been a 17-hours-to-expiration bounty; the question was posted on `2010-10-08 08:00:48Z` and the above comment was posted on `2010-10-11 14:36:40Z`. The bounty was initially posted on `2010-10-11 08:13:02Z`, and doesn't expire until next week.

Since the bounty cannot be awarded until at least 24 hours have been passed, the earliest it can be awarded is `2010-10-12 08:13:02Z`. Which is roughly 17 hours from when the quoted comment was posted, if you round down. This is likely what the author was referring to - when trying to award the bounty, a warning popped up saying 17 hours had to pass. So the author just cited it for you. No funny business of any sort.

Comment: Kinda what I was saying, only with the proper wording. +1

Comment: Thanks.  I didn't suspect any funny business; I was really just curious as to how the mechanism works.  Thank you very much for the clear explanation.

Answer (score 1):

That's odd. All bounties are *supposed* to be exactly seven days long, with absolutely **no exceptions**. I don't see an awarded bounty on the question you linked, but I do see the open bounty you referred to and your accepted answer.

When you answered, was there a message like this on the question:

> This question has an open bounty worth +xxx reputation from yyy ending in 17 hours.

or some other message? As of a few months ago, bounties and accepted answers are completely independent of each other, so I'm wondering if you saw some other message and were still working under the old definition of bounty. More details on the change are described in the blog [here](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/improvements-to-bounty-system/).

Comment: Thanks for the concern; I'm sure I was just confused.